# How to override jira aui.css

Tags: css, jira-plugin

I am trying to override the default dialog header styling in https://aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.9.5/css/aui.css. When I try to change the css in my custom css file it is not reflected.

```
.aui-dialog2-header-main{
      overflow: visible;
      white-space: normal;
    }
```

I know I can download the file and modify it directly but I would like to use the cdn in order to keep it updated.

Comment: Have you tried to verify it with the inspector? Maybe it is simply overriden by a more specific rule in original css. In this case you could user `!important` attribute to have the highest specificity

Comment: I tried it with !important but that's also not working. using the inpsector in chrome it shows the also original css rules not the one I am trying to implement.

Comment: Ok, so for some reason your css is not loaded.The problem is not in CSS code but in the way with you load your external file.....

Comment: This is how I have defined it     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//aui-cdn.atlassian.com/aui-adg/5.9.5/css/aui.css" media="all">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{furl '/css/addon.css'}}" type="text/css" /> It works fine in the case when I am not over-riding the actual css.

Answer (score 1):

you have to tag it as "important" to override the .

```
.aui-dialog2-header-main{
  overflow: visible !important;
  white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried it with !important but that's also not working.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the selector and order of the css.
The order being like this, where the top is the least prioritzed:

- Browser default
- External style sheet
- Internal style sheet
- Inline style

In addition to this the latest appearance of the selector / file will also be the one being used, also overruled by !important, however it will only take the latest !important rule if there's multiple.

So for example; you include 1.css and 2.css in that order, if same selector occurs in both files, the selectors in 2.css will be the ones used.

As you mentioned you have used chrome developer to check the css. Also use this to copy the CSS selector that you want to change the CSS for. And make sure that your custom CSS is being included after the aui.css file.

Edit: 
Also check that your custom CSS is "overridden" in the inspect window to see if it has loaded properly.

For references check;

http://monc.se/kitchen/38/cascading-order-and-inheritance-in-css

Comment: when i use the inspector it does work but once i add the same styling inside the custom css it fails to load. Ofcourse the custom css is below the original css so that to override the default.

Comment: I was thinking that you should copy the selector from the inspector, some times it requires a more specific selector e.g. if the AUI uses this selector h2.aui-dialog2-header-main or something you also need to use the same selector opposed to .aui-dialog2-header-main alone. Any code you write in the top part of the selector as default will be in-line CSS and top prio.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding css through jQuery? Hope it works.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".aui-dialog2-header-main").css({"overflow": "visible", "white-space": "normal"});   
 });
</script>
```